# Can i find the number of people who are currently checked-in in a facebook place?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-checkins

I want to build a desktop application which searches for the number of people who are currently checked-in in a facebook place, something like an equivalent for the foursquare's [hereNow](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/herenow).

I've searched quite a lot in the graph api but i can't find something that can help me. The only relative thing that i can take as a response for sure is the total checkins that have been made for a specific place. Does anyone know how and if what i look for can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may be able to use [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) to get up to 500 checkins for a certain page or place ID.
But it looks like the "here now" functionality may be left up to you, you may have to only display checkins with a timestamp within the last few hours.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! I 've seen the opportunity FQL gives you to search for checkins in a specific place using its id, but unfortunately it returns only the checkins your friends have make or have been tagged to. The other thing you said is what i am actually working on right now. I try to get total checkins for a place in different timestamps (for example every hour) and calculate the difference for an estimation of how many people passed from the place through that hour. I will not take your answer as the right one for now in case we both missed something. Thanks again though!

Comment: Have you tried using FQL and using a page access_token instead of a user access_token this may show you all checkins instead of just friends.